# java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported return false in javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

I have this javafx controller method trying to open up a local html file that's generated by the application. The function is running in another thread.

My main class that starts the application, using fxmlloader:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoAppiumProjectApplication extends Application
{

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoAppiumProjectApplication.class, args);
        Application.launch(DemoAppiumProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
        throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("JS SDK Demo Test Suite");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createRoot()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Parent createRoot()
        throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(DemoAppiumProjectApplication.class.getResource("/setup.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }
}
```

My controller class:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        Task<String> task = new Task<String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String call()
                throws Exception
            {
                showFinalDialog();
                return null;
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

public void showFinalDialog()
    {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            String text = "Test is complete! Click to view test report.";
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, text, ButtonType.OK);
            alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            Optional<ButtonType> buttonType = alert.showAndWait();
            if (!buttonType.isPresent())
            {
                Platform.exit();
            }
            else if (buttonType.get() == ButtonType.OK)
            {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Desktop.getDesktop()
                            .open(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/ExtentReport.html"));
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        createAlertWindow(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now the only question is the condition Desktop.isDesktopSupported return false here. I wrote another main function in another project to test again, it returns true.

I guess that means Desktop is supported on my OS (windows 10), but not supported in my javafx application?

So what am I missing here?

And perhaps there's another recommanded way to open up this html file as well? Any ideas would help! Thanks!

Comment: How are you running your javafx program? Also, can you make a complete compilable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: How do you know it returned false?

Comment: are you using spring for this application?

Comment: I use spring boot to start the application. I know this returns false when I run it in debug mode. I will add more code.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the Desktop to open a local html file when you are using javafx already.

Here is an example.

```
public class HelpWindow extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Help Window");

        WebView view = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.load( HelpWindow.class.getResource("help.html").toString());
        root.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 790, 675);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println(Desktop.isDesktopSupported());
    }    
}
```

That will show the `help.html` file, that I have included as a resource. From the looks of it, you might be generating your .html file so you would have to get the file a different way.

```
<html>
<body>
 <p> Here is some text</p>
 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/61362829/2067492">original question</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also included printing out the `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` since that returns true for me.

I suspect one issue you are having is that `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` is non-blocking, so your application just quits before your desktop can actually open the webpage.

Comment: Note that if you do want to use the system browser, the JavaFX way to do it is [`Application.getHostServices().showDocument(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String))